# PHP/Mysql: A db entry needs to store multiple values for categorization (cat, subcat, tags)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design, categories

This problem I'm facing may sound trivial to you but I'm wondering, beside ENUM type, what can one use to store numerical values for category, subcategory and multiple tags in a single column?

Scenario:

a DB entry needs to have category (id=4), subcategory(id=43) and tags(id=78,id=85,id=98,id=112, etc.)

tbl_entry has a column "categories" or similar to that, with the aim to hold those values (4,43,7,85,98,112,...)

Is ENUM really suitable and recommended way of storing it?

However, I am thinking about leaving out such a column completely and apply somewhat Wordpress-like solution - create taxonomies (cat, subcat, tag), and then in another table called relationships put the ID of my entry to be paired with correct taxonomies. The issue with this solution is that 50,000 entries would produce so many relationship rows (1 for cat, 1 for subcat, but up to 20 for tags).

Can you elaborate at the proposed ways and/or suggest new one(s)?

EDITS

Below is a suggestion to avoid storing multiple values in a single column at all costs. Acknowledged and appreciated!

I'm thinking about creating 3 separate tables for cat, subcat, tags.
Additionally, this way I may be able to employ Martin Fowler's pattern "Data Mapper" with "Table inheritance" for handling this aspect of my app (categorization of entries).

Comment: You probably should read "SQL Antipatterns" book: http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns

Answer (score 1):

NEVER EVER store multiple values in a single column, if you want to access them seperately - this is an accident waiting to happen!

Just forget the multi-id column, however it might be implemented: Think of what would be needed to find all rows, that have some tag: You would need to textually parse all rows' multi-vlue field, throwing away most of them: Every query becomes a full table scan with calculation - worst case.

The canonical way to do this, which is to have a join table with the relationships, might produce lots of records, but those are accessible in a furiously fast way, as they in fact are just indices.

Breaking this up into a a categories join table and a tags join table might or might not speed things up even further, depending on how often your business logic needs only one of those.

Comment: Thanks, so that's one option out. Not bad. I can tell you that I'm going to need all of the 3 almost all the time - entry is displayed, and cat & subcat text is displayed above or below it. Tags may be displayed only on demand but I'm not sure if that will change.

Answer (score 1):

Why you need to store it in the same column, make different tables for each as Category, Subcategory and Tags with one to one, one to many relationships resp. 
Use Indexes/FKs and JOINs to get records

Comment: It seemed more convenient to me. But then I read that enum is evil thing and should be avoided. Also, I will do as Eugen Rieck suggests - avoid storing multiple values in a single column.
Now I'm left with what you suggest and what Wordpress does (several interconnected tables - terms, taxonomies, relationships). Relationships are held in wp_relationships table where object_id is actually the ID of entry (wp post).

Comment: I forgot: How do you think I could reference the cat, MULTIPLE subcats and MULTIPLE tags for a single entry? A column for each of them is not an option, obviously..

Comment: But, I didn't say you to store multiple comma separated values in a single column, What I am saying is why you need to store it at all... for example: for each wp post, make an entry to category(if new), one entry to sub-category(if new) with the category_id as FK,multiple entries to Tags with sub_categoryid as FK. Makes sense yeah?

Comment: This is not a WP app, I'm just thinking about architecting my categorization related tables to be similar to Wordpress'.

Yes, now it's more clear what you meant. A good suggestion indeed, not quite the same as WP's solution but it should work.

Comment: See the idea is, lets say you have three tables, 
Post(id,desc,category_id,tag_id), Category(id,parent_id,name), Tags(id,name)
subcategory not needed, because you can make another column in the category table itself to make it sub category.
Advantage:
1) No another table needed
2) you can have any no of hierarchy 

Ok, now for every post done, 
you search if category already present, if tag already present
if yes get the corresponding ids n insert then in the post table...
else create new category/tags and get ids 
is that you wanted?

Comment: Pretty close but it seems I can have only one tag per post/entry? I need to have up to 20.

Comment: 10s-100s-1000s unless you link the same post id :)